# New domain not working in chrome

Tags: domains, dns, google-cloud

I've been coding a website as part of my development. Nothing fancy. Mostly CSS/HTML with a an external js carousel.

I purchased the domain through google and I'm hosting via google cloud using firebase. I've authenticated and changed the settings to input the dns and the 'A' record details. If I go to the web address on my mobile or using Opera I can see the site appears to be live. However, for chrome the name does not appear to be resolving.

I've flushed the dns in command prompt
I've restarted my router (but not my virgin modem) --could this be the issue?
I've ran "chrome://net-internals/#dns" and cleared the chrome cache

Any other suggestions with an explanation as to why this is happening (I'm eager to learn).

Comment: Do not use browsers to test DNS problems. Use DNS tools. There are several online tools to test and validate your DNS settings. Also use tools like the CLI `curl`.

Comment: "Any other suggestions with an explanation as to why this is happening (I'm eager to learn)." Then give the name involved.